# Looking for an expression evaluator

Tags: java

I'm looking for an evaluator for simple condition expressions.
Expressions should include variables (read only), strings, numbers and some basic operators.

E.g. expressions something like this:

```
${a} == "Peter" && ( ${b} == null || ${c} > 10 )
```

So far i implemented a rather "magical" parser that returns an AST that i can evaluate, but i can't believe that i'm the first one to solve that problem.

What existing code could i use instead?

Comment: What language/grammar are you looking to evaluate? Is it something you've made up? What does Java have to do with this?

Comment: I guess the OP wants something that runs on the JVM.

Comment: We've used JEP on a project (http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) but I'd really like a small, adaptable equivalent that could actually produce bytecode for a function for performance reasons.  We abandoned JEP for this reason, and ended up handcoding a huge number of Java classes.  Maybe an enterprising soul with ANTLR and BCEL could do this?

Comment: @Matt Ball: The example is a made up syntax that i'm using right now. But when i find a parser that's meets my demands i can go with whatever syntax it accepts. My main aim syntax-wise is to keep it as minimalistic as possible, because we may have many (think up to 200) of these tiny conditions in a single set. So, readability and performance are an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about SPEL (Spring Expression Lang); http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html

Comment: It's too late now, but that looks pretty much what i was looking for. It is focused on evaluating, but you have a getAST method that returns the expression structure.

Answer (score 16):

Have you looked at [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/)?  They provide a [getting started guide](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Getting+Started+for+2.0) and [performance analysis](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Performance+of+MVEL+2.0).

Here's one of their simple examples:

```
// The compiled expression is serializable and can be cached for re-use.
CompiledExpression compiled = MVEL.compileExpression("x * y"); 

Map vars = new HashMap();
vars.put("x", new Integer(5));
vars.put("y", new Integer(10));

// Executes the compiled expression
Integer result = (Integer) MVEL.executeExpression(compiled, vars); 
assert result.intValue() == 50;
```

Also (answering my own question) MVEL seems to provide some support for [bytecode generation](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Optimizers).

Other alternatives, culling from the above answers and my own:

- [Java Expression Parser (JEP)](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/) -- and note there is an [old version available for free](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jep/)
- Apache Commons [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/)
- With regard to Rhino, [here's a dude](http://weblog.plexobject.com/?p=1590) who did some arithmetic evaluation in that context (looks messy)

Comment: MVEL project documentation has been moved from codehaus. The link location is http://mvel.documentnode.com/. github location is - https://github.com/mvel/mvel.

Comment: But MVEL has a problem with the string like this @{'11412Test'} or @{'Test11412'} it wont be able to parse the above text and throws an error Caused by: [Error: invalid number literal: 11412Test]

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/) might work well for you. Check out its [syntax reference.](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/reference/syntax.html)

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use **Rhino**? It's a JavaScript engine already present inside the JDK.

It can evaluate whatever you like to write in JS.. take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29)

Comment: In fact we're using Rhino for larger custom scripts already. But i don't want to give these small expressions the full power of a scripting language.

Answer (score 3):

This simple [recursive descent parser](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/enumerated-functions) evaluates constants as named functions having no parameters.

Comment: When i'll replace magic with science i'll go that way. But right now i'm looking for an existing solution.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple and easy to use [alternative](http://github.com/Shy-Ta/expression-evaluator-demo) with a lot of built in excel functions for string, date and number formatting.

The library also allows easy addition of custom functions. A lot of examples available on the git page. A simple example using variables

```
  ExpressionsEvaluator evalExpr = ExpressionsFactory.create("LEFT(City, 3)");
  Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  variables.put("City", "New York");
  assertEquals("New", evalExpr.eval(variables));
```

Comment: That looks really promising for an out of the box solution. But i eventually went for Antlr and built my own expression language.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Skyost/Algogo/wiki/Algogo-Core#evalute-an-expression) is a little library I've worked on that supports expression evaluation (including variables, strings, boolean, etc...).

A little example :

```
String expression = "EXP(var)";
ExpressionEvaluator evaluator = new ExpressionEvaluator();
evaluator.putVariable(new Variable("var", VariableType.NUMBER, new BigDecimal(20)));

System.out.println("Value of exp(var) : " + evaluator.evaluate(expression).getValue());
```