# Method for evaluating math expressions in Java

Tags: java, math, formula

In one of my projects I want to add a feature where the user can provide in a formula, for example

```
sin (x + pi)/2 + 1
```

which I use in my Java app

```
/**
 * The formula provided by the user
 */
private String formula; // = "sin (x + pi)/2 + 1"

/*
 * Evaluates the formula and computes the result by using the
 * given value for x
 */
public double calc(double x) {
    Formula f = new Formula(formula);
    f.setVar("x", x);
    return f.calc();
    // or something similar
}
```

How can I evaluate math expressions?

Comment: I already used google, but all libs within the first 20 results were neither open source nor free. So, what does your google find?

Comment: It's a broad problem as posed.  I'd recommend creating a grammar and lexer/parser.  Create an AST and evaluate the expression by walking the tree.  Start simple and widen the circle by modifying the grammar.  You need to define what constitutes a valid expression that can be evaluated and what cannot.  Arithmetic and trig functions are one thing; Bessel and integral functions are another.

Answer (score 30):

There's also [exp4j](http://projects.congrace.de/exp4j), an expression evaluator based on [`Dijkstra's Shunting Yard`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). It's freely available and redistributable under the Apache License 2.0, only about 25KB in size, and quite easy to use:

```
Calculable calc = new ExpressionBuilder("3 * sin(y) - 2 / (x - 2)")
        .withVariable("x", varX)
        .withVariable("y", varY)
        .build()
double result1=calc.calculate();
```

When using a newer API version like `0.4.8`:

```
Expression calc = new ExpressionBuilder("3 * sin(y) - 2 / (x - 2)")
    .variable("x", x)
    .variable("y", y)
    .build();
double result1 = calc.evaluate();
```

There's also a facility to use custom functions in [exp4j](http://projects.congrace.de/exp4j).

Comment: it is not support for scientific notation: eg 1.5e+3*x

Comment: support for scientific notation has been added to exp4j 0.3.5 onward

Answer (score 14):

To extend the list, I just have finished one, too:

https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx

EvalEx is a handy expression evaluator for Java, that allows to evaluate simple mathematical and boolean expressions.

Key Features:

- Uses BigDecimal for calculation and result
- Single class implementation, very compact
- No dependencies to external libraries
- Precision and rounding mode can be set
- Supports variables
- Standard boolean and mathematical operators
- Standard basic mathematical and boolean functions
- Custom functions and operators can be added at runtime

Examples:

```
BigDecimal result = null;

Expression expression = new Expression("1+1/3");
result = expression.eval():
expression.setPrecision(2);
result = expression.eval():

result = new Expression("(3.4 + -4.1)/2").eval();

result = new Expression("SQRT(a^2 + b^2").with("a","2.4").and("b","9.253").eval();

BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("2.4");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("9.235");
result = new Expression("SQRT(a^2 + b^2").with("a",a).and("b",b).eval();

result = new Expression("2.4/PI").setPrecision(128).setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP).eval();

result = new Expression("random() > 0.5").eval();

result = new Expression("not(x<7 || sqrt(max(x,9)) <= 3))").with("x","22.9").eval();
```

Comment: it shows cos(rad(90)) as 0.996 :/ 
otherwise a great

Comment: To quote an answer to another question: BigDecimal does not provide these methods because BigDecimal models a rational number. Trigonometric functions, square roots and powers to non-integers (which I guess includes square roots) all generate irrational numbers.

These can be approximated with an arbitrary-precision number but the exact value can't be stored in a BigDecimal.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173512/java-bigdecimal-trigonometric-methods

Comment: Why should this be 1? even my desktop calculator show as a result 0,99962421686273250535510392708914 ...

Comment: Another Issue, I dont think there is a provision for adding operators like !(factorial). Edit, I have been taught since birth that cos(0) is 1. dont tell me that my life is a lie :O

Comment: Factorial can be very easily implemented as a (custom) function, prefix operators are not supported.

Comment: for that , i will have to use !(expression), right ?

Comment: The ! character is not supported as a function name, you can use e.g. FAC(expression)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57345/discussion-between-harvey-slash-and-udo-klimaschewski).

Comment: I was just looking at your library, but it appears that it does not support nested expressions, does it? Ex: new Expression( "2*var2").with("var2", "5*var1" ).with( "var1", "10" ); When I tried that, I got an exception thrown.

Answer (score 11):

It depends how complex are the expressions you want to eval but for simple ones, java has a javascript engine that works pretty well:

```
import javax.script.*;
public class EvalScript {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create a script engine manager
    ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
    // create a JavaScript engine
    ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    // evaluate JavaScript code from String
    Object obj = engine.eval("1+2");
    System.out.println( obj );
    }
}
```

Comment: The functions will be more complex than the one I used in my question. They will contain trigonometric functions as well as exponentiations and so on. I don't think the JS eval() function can do that.

Comment: There's no way I would prefer this technique. It's wide open to injection attacks, like almost all such techniques based on a generic eval. Bad practice.

Comment: @JohnO what do you propose then ? I am really not an expert at web programming.

Comment: @Snicolas - In general, I would use a tool which has strict parsing of the input, which would restrict it to math expressions only, with no possibility of executing arbitrary code.

Comment: @JohnO You could whitelist what can go into the eval string. I like this example because it's native Java. Also, if you don't accept input from untrusted sources, it's fine as is

Answer (score 3):

Nice math parser containing broad math collection - [mXparser](http://mathparser.org/) - please see the examples:

Example 1:

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Argument x = new Argument("x = pi");
Expression e = new Expression("sin(x + pi)/2 + 1", x);
mXparser.consolePrintln("Res 1: " + e.getExpressionString() + " = " + e.calculate());
x.setArgumentValue(2);
mXparser.consolePrintln("Res 2: " + e.getExpressionString() + " = " + e.calculate());
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] Res 1: sin(x + pi)/2 + 1 = 1.0
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] Res 2: sin(x + pi)/2 + 1 = 0.545351286587159
```

Example 2:

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Function f = new Function("f(x) = sin(x + pi)/2 + 1");
Expression e = new Expression("f(pi)", f);
mXparser.consolePrintln("Res: " + e.getExpressionString() + " = " + e.calculate());
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] Res: f(pi) = 1.0
```

For better understanding please follow [mXparser tutorial](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/) and [mXparser math collection](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-math-collection/).

Found recently - in case you would like to try the syntax (and see the advanced use case) you can download the [Scalar](https://scalarmath.org) [Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mathparser.scalar.lite) [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mathparser.scalar.pro) that is powered by mXparser.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Adding another option to the list, I wrote Jep Java which gained a lot of popularity as an [open source project on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jep/).

It supports all the basic common tasks of expression parsing. But it also adds a lot of extendibility if you want to customize it. A lot of users have praised the library for being especially well written and easy to use. See the sourceforge reviews!

Here is a simple example with a single variable:

```
import com.singularsys.jep.Jep;

Jep jep = new Jep();
jep.addVariable("x", 10);
jep.parse("x+1");
Object result = jep.evaluate();
System.out.println("x + 1 = " + result);
```

This will print "x + 1 = 11". You can change the value of variables and quickly evaluate the expression again.

I later also made the library available with a commercial license on the [Singular Systems website](http://www.singularsys.com/jep).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Added an example on how Jep is used.

Comment: this is a great library.

Answer (score 1):

I have a small-footprint yet very capable [math evaluator](http://tech.dolhub.com/Code/MathEval) which is completely unencumbered.

#### Primary Features

- Basic math operators, with inferred precedence (`+` `-` `*` `×` `/` `÷` `%` `^`).
- Explicit precedence with parenthesis.
- Implicit multiplication of bracketed subexpressions.
- Correct right-associativity of exponentials (power operator).
- Direct support for hexadecimal numbers prefixed by `0x`.
- Constants and variables.
- Extensible functions.
- Extensible operators.
- Tiny 20 KiB footprint.

Here's a simple example which calculates the middle column of the subsection of a text display (biased left).

```
MathEval            math=new MathEval();

math.setVariable("Top",    5);
math.setVariable("Left",  20);
math.setVariable("Bottom",15);
math.setVariable("Right", 60);

System.out.println("Middle: "+math.evaluate("floor((Right+1-Left)/2)"));                        // 20
```

Comment: I've taken a quick look at your site/code and overall looks interesting.  Do you have any unit tests for it and/or packaged jars?  I can easily import your Java src file into my code, but would have preferred a maven artifact if there was one.

Comment: No, I quite deliberately avoid the complications of publishing anything more than raw source code. I do have a test class, but will not be publishing it.

Comment: Why not publish the test class as well?  Would it not help with understanding how the MathEval class works, as well as provide comfort that everything works as expected?

Comment: Does this support imaginary numbers?

Comment: @Henry: No. But the extension capabilities *could possibly* be used to add a unary operator `i` so that `123i` might function as needed. However, I don't know enough to be certain as to whether that's viable. And there's a potentially inherent conflict with named variables, though that might be mitigated by using some other symbol to indicate "imaginary". But it seems highly unlikely to me.

Answer (score 0):

I already have posted a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51162257/3608831). I just wanted to say that I have been worked on a little library that supports math, boolean and string expression evaluation. Here is a small example :

```
String expression = "EXP(var)";
ExpressionEvaluator evaluator = new ExpressionEvaluator();
evaluator.putVariable(new Variable("var", VariableType.NUMBER, new BigDecimal(20)));

System.out.println("Value of exp(var) : " + evaluator.evaluate(expression).getValue());
```

If you are interested, it is available [here](https://github.com/Skyost/Algogo/wiki/Algogo-Core#evalute-an-expression).

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [ParserNG](https://github.com/gbenroscience/ParserNG), a full fledged and extremely fast math expression parser which works in compile-evaluate phases.
The compile phase parses/understands the expression. The evaluate phase solves it and is extremely fast.

I called it a parser, but it is more than that.

It evaluates math expressions, supports creation and usage of variables and constants, supports inbuilt and creation of custom functions, solves quadratic equations, simultaneous equations, Tartaglia's equations(`a.x^3+b.x+c=0`), solves also equations in a single variable by iterative means(using a number of fallback techniques), does basic statistics, differential calculus(includes its own implementation of a symbolic differentiator which it uses to spit out numerical values for derivatives at given values), solves numerical integrals.

It also handles matrices via a Function class and supports various matrix operations using matrix functions.

And that is not even all.

As an example, here is the parser doing some differential calculus:

```
MathExpression expr = new MathExpression("f(x)=x^3*ln(x); diff(f,3,1)"); 
System.out.println("result: " + expr.solve());

 result: 38.66253179403897
```

See more information about it in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969561/how-to-parse-mathematical-expressions-involving-parentheses/55852113#55852113)