# Is there a package in Java that reads mathematical functions (like a calculator does)?

Tags: java, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [free Java library for evaluating math expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions)

I was wondering if there's a package in Java that can take in a string, say "x^2+e^x*cos(x)", and evaluate it as a mathematical function given a value of x like a calculator would -- ideally one that's free and publicly available. Does this exist?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587557/good-symbolic-math-cas-library-for-jav

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/java-evaluate-string-to-math-expression - this too

google: java string math

Comment: One way is to use the [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html).  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441625/how-to-find-a-button-source-in-awt-calculator-homework/7441804#7441804) for an example.  @Thilo notes *"I'd be careful with ScriptEngine if direct user input is involved, though. A tailored math library might be better."*

Answer (score 0):

There are lots - It's a fairly simple and common parser-writing exercise so lots of people have had a go and published some code. See e.g.:

- http://jeval.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/algorithms-recursion/605-java-calculator.html
- https://webspace.utexas.edu/anl234/calc/

The likely issue will be the range of mathematical functions available. You can expect the standard ones, but may need to customise / add your own for the more unusual functions ([cosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_cosine) perhaps?)

Another option is to embed a language interpreter, e.g. [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) to do the calculations. This is a bit more heavyweight and means that you will need to be much more conscious of security risks (e.g. if the code might get run on a server) but could make sense if you have a more general need for scripting.