# Does Java have a libraries or functionality capable of evaluating arbitrary arithmetic expressions using BODMAS order of evaluation

Tags: java

Can we make calculator program using [BODMAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) rule by something like this in Java :

```
String valfromtextbox = "2(2*2)+5";

long total = Long.parseLong(valfromtextbox);
```

Can we do something like above or we have to make entire logic to do this.

If we have to make entire logic then please give me hint.

Comment: You need to look up either: recursive descent parsing; Shunting Yard Algorithm; Java Script Engine; or use of a parser generator such as JavaCC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [free Java library for evaluating math expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use [Java Expression Language (JEXL)](http://commons.apache.org/jexl/):

```
    // Create or retrieve a JexlEngine
    JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
    // Create an expression object
    String valfromtextbox = "2(2*2)+5";
    Expression e = jexl.createExpression( valfromtextbox );

    // Create a context and add data
    JexlContext jc = new MapContext();

    // Now evaluate the expression, getting the result
    Object o = e.evaluate(jc);
```