# Convert math equation to Java BigDecimal line

Tags: java

I am trying to make a small tool that transfers a math equation to a Java BigDecimal line.

for example:

```
A + B * C => A.add(B.multiply(C))
A / B + C => A.divide(B).add(C)
```

Things are getting nasty with brackets.

```
A - (B + C) / D => A.substract(B.add(C).divide(D))
A - (B * (C + D)) => A.substract(B.multiply(C.add(D)))
```

My approach is to do it recursively.
for example: A + B * C

```
1. convert( A + B * C ) 
2. A.add( convert (B * C) )
3. A.add(B.multiply(C))
```

Math Symbols that supports: `+ - * / % ( )`

I was wondering if there is a better way to handle this.

Is there a name for this kind of issue is it? Compiler? (Sorry if it is not, I have never done any work with compiler.)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are writing a very basic compiler or interpreter. You could google these two words to find some helpful information.

Comment: Also look up grammar parsers.

Comment: Pretty much what you want to do is make a parse tree and then traverse the tree with depth first search. Your lowest nodes would have the highest precedence. As others have said, this is very similar to (certain steps of) compiler design.

Comment: If your main goal is to evaluate the expressions take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions

Comment: Thanks for the replies. :) I guess I need to dig into it a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at a [*recursive descent parser*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), illustrated [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/enumerated-functions) for `double` values. The change to `BigDecimal` is straightforward, but you may have to scale back on the named functions.

Comment: Looking closer, I think you can add `%` as another `mulop` and implement it with `remainder()`.

Answer (score 1):

why not use Groovy?  It directly supports nicer syntax for big decimal arithmetic.

```
BigDecimal a = ...;
BigDecimal b = ...;
BigDecimal c = ...;
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("A", a);
binding.setVariable("B", b);
binding.setVariable("C", c);
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);

BigDecimal value = (BigDecimal) shell.evaluate("a+b*c");
```

Groovy also has a direct literal syntax for big decimals as well if you need it;

```
A = 2G
B = 4G
C = 8G
```

If your primary goal is simply to input expressions and evaluate them, this is a nice simple approach.  If you're trying to generate code, that's a different story.

Comment: ps:  http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Math   you'll get the power operator too, and type coercion if you need it.