# Small Java open-source math expression evaluator that binds with Apache commons math

Tags: java, parsing, math, expression, complex-numbers

I've been searching google for a while now but can't find what I need.
I need an open source mathematical expression parser & evaluator - of which there are a myriad -
But one which links to a decent math library like Apache Commons Math. I need complex arithmetic, basic functions like sin, log that work on complex plane, and functions like gamma, erf.

The closest answer I found was [Built-in method for evaluating math expressions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions) - but I couldn't see how, other than writing countless helper functions, to bind

- jexpr
- jruby
- jeval
- javax.script

with Commons math. Also it would take quite some work to modify my own existing (real-valued) expression parser to bind all the functions.

Plus, including a whole scripting programming language like python/ruby in my app seems overkill, where what I want to do is barely more than an old-fashioned pocket calculator.

**Hasn't someone done this sort of thing already**?
Thanks!

Comment: Just to summarise, what I'd like is a parser that **binds with math libraries** without extra effort.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out an implementation that I created:

https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx.

It is based on `java.math.BigDecimal`and supports the basic matehmatical and boolean operations.
It is a very compact implementation: only a single class file without any dependencies to other libraries. Plus, it can be easily extended with custom functions and operators.

Your `gamma(1.8)` example can be added in this way:

```
Expression e = new Expression("gamma(1.8)");

e.addFunction(e.new Function("gamma", 1) {
    @Override
    public BigDecimal eval(List<BigDecimal> parameters) {
        BigDecimal gamma = MyMathLibraryGammaCalculation(parameters.get(0));
        return gamma;
    }
});

e.eval(); // returns gamma(1.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

We used to do this with ScriptEngine for javascript - Not sure if that is sufficient for your requirements... here is a reference in SA:

[Is there an eval() function in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. But I'm not sure that really works for my purpose - unless I missed something. I have written my own parsers that do most of what I need, but the work is in the linking with good math libraries and complex arithmetic operators, and linking with a standard function library. The idea is that users will be able to write `gamma(1.8)` and it will know to direct the function to the math library.