# calculate values of an array using operators in another array

Tags: java, arrays, math, operators

I have 2 arrays :

```
int[] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int[] operators = {PLUS, MINUS, MULTIPLY, MINUS, DIVIDE, PLUS}
```

UPPERCASE words in brackets are defined constants. 
i want to use corresponding operators (+, -, *, /, +) to evaluate the values in the `values array` :

```
1 + 2 - 3 * 4 / 5 + 6 = 1 + 2 - (3*4/5) + 6 = 6.6 // expected result
```

i have created a method (with a `switch case`), based on the above constants to know wich operators i should use.

```
public static int evaluate(int a, int b, int op) {
    int result = 0;
    switch (op) {
    case PLUS:
        result = a + b;
        break;

    case MINUS:
        result = a - b;
        break;
            /* .... */
    }

    return result;
}
```

But as you see, with this method the result will be wrong: that's why when executed i got :

```
1+2-3*4/5+6 = ((((1+2)-3)*4)/5)+6 = 0*4/5+6 = 0 / 5 + 6 = 0 + 6 = 6 // not the expected result
```

somebody can help me ?

**SOLUTION : JEval**

@AudriusMeškauskas's link contains a list of (powerful) libraries. I read [`JEval` features](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/), i tested it an i it works like a charm !

```
Evaluator evaluator = new Evaluator();
System.out.println("eval : " + evaluator.evaluate("1 + 2 - 3 * 4 / 5 + 6"));
```

**output** : `6.6`

Comment: In your example you never use the second -. You should have 1 operator less than the number of literals

Comment: I would say, [use some freely available library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions) to evaluate Math expressions.

Comment: thanks @AudriusMeškauskas, JEval may solve my problem ! i will come back !

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas JEval did the stuff ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Edsger Dijkstra published a solution to this in 1961.  It's called the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).  A copy of the original paper is available [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/MCReps/MR35.PDF) (pdf), in case you're interested.  It takes into account the precedence of the operators, rather than simply computing from left to right, as your original solution did.  I suspect the Evaluator class uses some variation on the Shunting Yard Algorithm to properly compute the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all temporary values with calculated results fo multiplication and division and at the end add/substarct rest.

The problem is not at this part of the source code and you have expand your application.

Your solution adds/substracts/multiplies/divides next number with previous result. You have to modify the method of calculations.

Example:

[Simple calculator](http://stevenrbrandt.com/cios/index.php/Regex.xml)

Comment: You can change the variables to doubles. They are better if you use the division, but this is not main problem in your application.

Comment: yes i know i am wrong with my method. Pliz can you give an example ? don't forget that you can have more than 20 values in the array !!

Comment: Link to calculator written in java is above, in my answer.

Comment: You do not need to store temporary results in the table;). Replace actual numbers with the result of multiplication/division.