# Adding numbers within a string in java

Tags: java, string, parsing, int

How do I add two numbers within one string?

I have:

```
String a = "(x+x)";
String lb = "2";

String b = a.replace("x", lb);

int c = ?
```

it outputs `2+2`, how do I get it to add them together correctly into an integer?

Comment: What's the issue in using it as a integer itself? Instead of putting it in String and trying to convert it back to integer.

Comment: Do you want to execute '2+2' string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [free Java library for evaluating math expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions)

Comment: It almost sounds like OP might be trying to implement some sort of evaluator for arithmetic expressions, perhaps unintentionally. In his example, he is printing the string "(2+2)" and expecting it to print "4". He might also be confused about String and integer types, but I wanted to throw out another possible explanation in case someone wants to expand on it.

Comment: `int lb = 2; System.out.println( "" + lb + "+" + lb ); System.out.println( lb+lb );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use a Java library to achieve this goal as mentioned in the comments, there **is** something built into Java since version 6 which may be useful (but maybe a little overkill). I suggest this not because I believe it's particularly efficient but rather as an alternative to using a library.

Use JavaScript:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

ScriptEngine jsRuntime = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
String expression = "2+2"; //The expression you would to evaluate.
double result = (Double) jsRuntime.eval(expression);
```

Comment: this is a very clever solution

Comment: Thank you, actually extremely helpful and will work for a wider variety of integrations.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Integer.parseInt` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) to parse a `String` into an `int`, then add the values.  Adding strings just concatenates them.

Comment: I guess OP wants/needs to retrieve it as `4` instead of `2+2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parseInt()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm) method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question could be summarised as

> How do I convert a String such as `"2+2"` to the number `4`

Here's a solution that uses only the standard Java libraries:

```
    String sumExpression = "2+2";
    String[] numbers = sumExpression.split("\\+");

    int total = 0;

    for (String number: numbers) {
        total += Integer.parseInt(number.trim());
    }

    // check our result
    assert total == 4;
```