# Condition String Resolver in java API?

Tags: java

I would like to resolve the following condtion string. Because I would like to support dynamic condtion in my project.

```
a != 0 && b > 5
```

My expected Program is

```
public boolean resolve() {
    String condition = "a != 0 && b > 5";
    Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap<String, Object>;
    paramMap.put("a", 2);
    paramMap.put("b", 6);
    boolean result = ConditionResolver.resolve(condition, paramMap);
    if(result) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

**Update :**

I am not trying to resolve the math equation, like below

```
((a + b) * y) /x
```

Comment: Why not you use expression libraries?

Comment: @Prateek, I want to use, but I don't know which API support for that simple condition

Comment: Please refer to my answer, may be it may help you out

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ not necessarily a duplicate, question is about logical expressions and not math expressions

Comment: @NarendraPathai Yes. Agreed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of java 1.6 you can use the `ScriptEngine` and evaluate *javascript* if this is enough for you and/or if you don't want to introduce another library.

```
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
SimpleBindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();

bindings.put("a", 0);
bindings.put("b", 6);

boolean firstEval =  (Boolean) scriptEngine.eval("a != 0 && b > 5", bindings);
System.out.println(firstEval);

bindings.put("a", 2);
bindings.put("b", 6);

boolean secondEval =  (Boolean) scriptEngine.eval("a != 0 && b > 5", bindings);
System.out.println(secondEval);
```

Output

```
false
true
```

Comment: is there any java local program rather than quoting other language's capability that can deal with logic computation ?

Comment: @Rene Link, You program is ok for my current requirement. Thanks for your providing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use expression libraries.May be this post will help you [Built-in method for evaluating math expressions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions)

For Evaluating Logical Expressions refer following library : [JANINO](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home)

#### EXAMPLE

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException;
import org.codehaus.janino.ExpressionEvaluator;

public class WorkSheet_1{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws CompileException, InvocationTargetException {
        ExpressionEvaluator ee = new ExpressionEvaluator(
                "a != 0 && b > 5",                     
                boolean.class,                           
                new String[] { "a", "b" },           
                new Class[] { int.class, int.class } 
            );

        Boolean res1 = (Boolean) ee.evaluate(new Object[] {new Integer(2), new Integer(6),});
        System.out.println("res1 = " + res1);
        Boolean res2 = (Boolean) ee.evaluate(new Object[] {new Integer(2), new Integer(5),});
        System.out.println("res2 = " + res2);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
res1 = true
res2 = false
```

Comment: I think, it is only resolve the math expression. Can solve condition string?

Comment: Java condition strings are different than math expressions.