# How to convert string to operator in java

Tags: java

I want to convert some `String` to an operator like this:

```
int value = 1;
int valueToCompare = 3;
String operation = "<";

if (value operation valueToCompare) {
    // some operation       
}
```

How do I convert a variable operation into an operator?

Comment: Only using conventions, e.g. that String "<" means that operation <

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may try this:

```
import java.util.*;

interface Operator {
  boolean compare(int a, int b);
}

class Launch
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Map<String, Operator> opMap = new HashMap<String, Operator>();
        opMap.put(">", new Operator() {
            @Override public boolean compare(int a, int b) {
                return a > b;
            }
        });
        opMap.put("<", new Operator() {
            @Override public boolean compare(int a, int b) {
                return a < b;
            }
        });
        opMap.put("==", new Operator() {
            @Override public boolean compare(int a, int b) {
                return a == b;
            }
        });
        String op = ">";
        int i = 4, j = 5;
        boolean test = opMap.get(op).compare(i, j);
        System.out.printf("test: %b, i: %d, op: %s, j: %d\n", test, i, op, j);
            //prints: test: false, i: 4, op: >, j: 5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach will never work in Java. Instead you may define your own `enum` which perform the proper boolean operation like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean result = Operator.parseOperator("==").apply(2, 2);
}

enum Operator {

    LESS("<") {
        @Override public boolean apply(int left, int right) {
            return left < right;
        }
    },
    EQUAL("==") {
        @Override public boolean apply(int left, int right) {
            return left == right;
        }
    };

    private final String operator;

    private Operator(String operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    public static Operator parseOperator(String operator) {
        for (Operator op : values()) {
            if (op.operator.equals(operator)) return op;
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException(String.format("Unknown operator [%s]", operator));
    }

    public abstract boolean apply(int left, int right);
}
```

Comment: Yeah you did! Nice job. As long as the proper solution is posted I am satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a [switch based around a string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/StringSwitchDemo.java) (for Java 7 and above - otherwise simple use `if`/`else`), and a set of [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) objects e.g.

```
switch (operation) {
   case ">" : return new GreaterThanComparator();
```

or

```
if (operation.equals(">")) {
   return new GreaterThanComparator();
}
```

where `GreaterThanComparator` implements the `Comparator` interface. The class you've created implements your comparison functionality and could do a lot more besides. It's the closest Java has to the encapsulation of a function.

Note that the `Comparator` above can be used directly in Java collections in order to perform [sorting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) etc.

You could use lookup tables (e.g. a `Map` of `String`/`Comparators`) or similar if you have a lot of these comparisons to make. I think the important part of the above is the encapsulation of the behaviour via the `Comparator` object.

An alternative is to use the [scripting engine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/) built into Java and parse (say) Javascript statements. That's perhaps more work, but certainly a more extensible solution. Note that you're not limited to Javascript, and a number of scripting languages exist, including Beanshell, Jython etc.

Comment: Yes this solution works, but it is not `OO`. It teaches procedural programming in my opinion.

Comment: I should point out that OO is a technique and not an end in itself. If you have a set of strings and want to map these to behaviour, at some stage you're going to have to perform some lookup via if/else, switch/case, tables etc. I note you have precisely the same set of lookups in your solution below, but encoded via a set of enums.

Comment: In fact (rereading) I'd suggest it's closer to teaching *functional* programming. Regardless, it's another technique/tool available for use amongst many, with various pros/cons

Comment: In my opinion a `switch` or huge `if-else` statement is always a candidate to rethink the approach and to consider a polymorphic solution. It is not always a must, but worth to re-evaluate the current solution. I can't see anything functional characteristics in `if-else` and `switch` statements. But this is an off-topic discussion and has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: That's not the functional bit. The functional bit is returning the stateless object implementing one method (the Comparator)

Comment: You mean like a closure? Your approach does construct a new instance every time. This will burden the garbage-collector more often then necessary I guess, right?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom method which does it for you..

Something like this

```
private static boolean parseExpression(int number1, String operator, int number2)
{
    if ("<".equals(operator)) {
        return number1 < number2;
    } else if (">".equals(operator)) {
        return number1 > number2;
    } else if ("<=".equals(operator)) {
        return number1 <= number2;
    } else if (">=".equals(operator)) {
        return number1 >= number2;
    } else if ("==".equals(operator)) {
        return number1 == number2;
    } else { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid operator");
    }
}

private static boolean parseExpression(double number1, String operator, double number2)
{
    if ("<".equals(operator)) {
        return Double.compare(number1, number2) == -1;
    } else if (">".equals(operator)) {
        return Double.compare(number1, number2) == 1;
    } else if ("<=".equals(operator)) {
        return Double.compare(number1, number2) <= 0;
    } else if (">=".equals(operator)) {
        return Double.compare(number1, number2) >= 0;
    } else if ("==".equals(operator)) {
        return Double.compare(number1, number2) == 0;
    } else if ("!=".equals(operator)) {
        return Double.compare(number1, number2) != 0;
    } else { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid operator");
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use a comparator, it's something "simple" but should work.
For double/floats should do a bit more of work anyway

---

P.S with Enums you could do something very elegant. With Java7 you can use `switch-strings` too.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be a chain of if-else statements checking what the the operator is and then performing the mathematical expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ScriptEngine for that, works for any other JavaScript expressions also :

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");


int value = 1;
int valueToCompare = 3;
String operation = "<";

if ((Boolean)engine.eval("" + value + operation + valueToCompare)) {
    System.out.println("Here we are.");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a **switch** statement:

```
switch(operation) {
    case "<" : //code here
        break;
    case ">" : //code here
        break;
    case "==" : //code here
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not directly possible, you'll have to write some code. One possibility is using enums:

```
enum Operation {
    LESS_THAN("<") {
        @Override int compare(int o1, int o2) {
            return o1 - o2;
        }
    },
    ...;

    private final String operator;
    private Operation(final String operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }

    private static final Map<Operation, String> MAP = new HashedMap<Operation, String>();
    static {
        for (final Operation op: values()) MAP.put(op.operator, op);
    }

    public static Operation valueOf(final String op) {
        return MAP.get(op);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
int cmp = Operation.valueOf(operation).compare(value, valueToCompare);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

For completeness¸I would like to add that there already exists a lot of code for this. I know you asked a very specific question, but the general answer would be to look at existing solutions how that is done.

Example:

[Built-in method for evaluating math expressions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions)