# How to compare two double values with string type of relation in java?

Tags: java

I need to compare two double values with relation type as string.
Eg:

```
String relation = "<=";
   double aAA=5.9,bBB=6.999999;
```

In the above example need to compare aAA relation bBB using java

Comment: `if (relation.equals("<=") { comparisonResult = a <= b; }`

Comment: A lot more background information and your own code attempts would help to greatly clarify this question/problem.

Comment: if I have list of relation is there like<=,>=,<,><,,== then I need many conditions.

Comment: this answer should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/23493336/5558072

Comment: You need 5. 5 is far from being many.

Comment: There is no built-in way of parsing `<=` as you desire. You will need to **map it** manually or use technologies that can **parse it**. Typical *eval* functions could do the trick, for example by using Javas built-in JavaScript interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `Map` mapping the Strings to the actual operations, e.g. as [`BiPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html).

```
Map<String, BiPredicate<Double, Double>> relations = new HashMap<>();
relations.put("<=", (a, b) -> a <= b);
relations.put(">=", (a, b) -> a >= b);
relations.put("==", (a, b) -> a == b);
// ...

String relation = "<=";
double aAA=5.9,bBB=6.999999;

boolean result = relations.get(relation).test(aAA, bBB);
```

Comment: I like the use of `BiPredicate`, makes the code pretty compact and readable.