# Evaluating a math expression given in string

Tags: java, string, math, expression, evaluation

Here is my code:

```
String test = "12+23-42-53+4-31";
        int counter = 0;
        Stack<Integer> numb= new Stack<Integer>();
        Stack<String> op = new Stack<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i<test.length();i++){
            if(test.charAt(i)=='-' || test.charAt(i)=='+'){
                int number = Integer.parseInt(test.substring(counter, i));
                counter=i+1;
                numb.push(number);
                String oper = Character.toString(test.charAt(i));
                op.push(oper);
            }

        }
```

If I loop through numb stack then the last number of test string is missing. Are there any solutions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions

Answer (score 1):

When you exit the for loop, you don't add the last number because there is no more "-" or "+" symbol at the end of your test String.

Just push the last number into the numb stack once you exit the for loop.

Hint: counter is the position where the last number starts, and the last position is the String length.

If you do it correct and print the stacks:

```
//Print the stacks to see result
System.out.println(numb.toString());
System.out.println(op.toString());
```

You will obtain following output:

```
[12, 23, 42, 53, 4, 31]
[+, -, -, +, -]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` statement, you test if the char is a `'-'` or a `'+'`. Then, you parse the number that comes before. So you should parse the last number after your `for`-loop finishes.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript");
Object o = engine.eval("12+23-42-53+4-31");
System.out.println(o);
```