# Converting string to math expression in android?

Tags: java, android, math

I have searched how to convert string "4+5" to math expression and i only found that i should use [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) but when i import the library in android studio it doesn't seem to work. Can you suggest any other ideas which would be good way how to convert string to math expression?

I used fro example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form) question and this is their code:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String foo = "40+2";
    System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Add error if any or at least code which you used.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions