# Showing Textview as String and integer

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` showing data like `5(25)+10(12)+13(10)` which is shown as a String. 
I want `5,25,10,12,13,10` as integer. How is it possible?.

```
Integer value= number.toString();
textview.settext(value);
```

Comment: It's not android related question, there is no easy way to do that :) so probably you need to check each char and implement some algorithm like Polish notation or other.

Comment: And you will have multiple integers as your string is containing multiple ones.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258538/free-java-library-for-evaluating-math-expressions

Comment: int i = Integer.valueOf(yourTextView.getText());

Comment: do you want to separate the numbers and make them Integers?

Comment: i want to separate the number and make them integerrs #vspallas

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
string value = 5 + "(" + 25 + ")"+10+"("+12+")" + 13+"("+10+")"
//this makes 5(25)10(12)12(10)
textView.setText(value)
```

If you have 5,25,10,12,13,10 externally as Integers:

```
int five = 5;
int twentyFive = 25;
int ten = 10;
int twelve = 12;
int thirteen = 13;
  string value = five + "(" + twentyFive + ")"+ten+"("+twelve+")" + thirteen+"("+ten+")"
    //this makes 5(25)10(12)12(10)
    textView.setText(value)
```

Comment: I want to separate the numbers and make them Integers?