# want a maven dependency which support BigDecimal-based custom formula calculation

Tags: java

I would like to achieve the following Code example so I can store the formula into database and reuse it:

```
Function fun = new Function("(${x}+${y})/${z}");            
Argument x = new Argument("x", BigDecimal.ValueOf("1.1"));
Argument y = new Argument("y", BigDecimal.ValueOf("1.1"));
Argument z = new Argument("y", BigDecimal.ValueOf("1.1"));
BigDecimal result = fun.calculate(x,y,z);
```

I have already tried other frameworks like `commons-jexl` and `mathparser`, but none of them support `BigDecimal`.

Comment: maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13975620/13527856, it seems to support `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Maven dependency](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx):

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.udojava</groupId>
            <artifactId>EvalEx</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

with this snippet:

```java
    System.out.println(
        new Expression( "(x + y) / z" )
                .with( "x", BigDecimal.valueOf( 1.1 ) )
                .and( "y", BigDecimal.valueOf( 1.1 ) )
                .and( "z", BigDecimal.valueOf( 1.1 ) )
                .eval()
    );
```

prints:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jtransc</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtransc-rt</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please add more information to the answer.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.