# How would I take user input and convert it to a runnable equation?

Tags: java, calculator, graphing

I am currently trying to make a graphing calculator in Java in which the user inputs an equation, for example, 3x^2+4x-14, which is fed into the program and graphed. How could I take any user equation and turn it into an equation in Java for a for loop to run?

I have already implemented methods that automatically detect if the user input is a viable equation, however I'm still stumped by actually taking that user input and converting it into a runnable algorithm.

Comment: Well, you can't turn it into something Java evaluates, but if you're only dealing with polynomials, it's not that hard.  Just use an array with the coefficients, and write a function that accepts that array and a value of x, and compute the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/7258538/2308683

Comment: for general expressions you need to learn some [parsing method](https://jonascarpay.com/posts/2021-05-16-parsing-programming-language.html) and build a parser.