# Evaluate command line argument as boolean expression

Tags: java, string, if-statement, boolean, evaluate

I'm trying to take a string, passed as an argument, and evaluate it as a boolean expression in an *if* conditional statement.  For example, the user invokes MyProgram like `$ java MyProgram x==y`.

---

##### Example Program

Defined variables:

```
int x;
int y;
```

Boolean expression argument:

```
String stringToEval = args[0];
```

Control program execution with user expression:

```
if (stringToEval) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Seems like some more detail is needed: He's not asking to convert `args[0]` to a Boolean from `true` or `false`, he's asking for some method of evaluating `x==y` or some other expression and applying it to `x` and `y` in the application.

Comment: @ChrisMantle Check my other answer, i treated what you are saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use some form of expression parser to parse the value in `args[0]` and create an expression that can be applied to `x` and `y`. You may be able to use something like [Janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home), [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/) or [Jeval](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/) to do this. You could also write a small parser yourself, if the inputs are well-defined.

Comment: See also the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010674/looking-for-an-expression-evaluator

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is a bit complexe, you need to evaluate the expression and extract the 2 arguments form the operation

```
String []arguments = extractFromArgs(args[0])
```

there you get `x` and `y` values in `arguments`

then:

```
if (arguments [0].equals(arguments[1]))
```

**If x and y are integers:**

```
int intX = new Integer(arguments[0]);
int intY = new Integer(arguments[0]);
if (intX == intY)
```

etc...

**PS: Why use Integer, Double ..? Because in String evaluation "2" is not equal to "2.0" whereas in Integer and Double evaluaiton, they are equal**

Answer (score 0):

What ever you are taking input as a command line argument is the String type and you want to use it as a Boolean so you need to covert a String into a boolean.

For doing this you have to Option either you use `valueOf(String s)` or `parseBoolean(String s)`

so your code must look like this,

```
S...
int x;
int y;
...
String stringToEval = args[0];
boolean b = Boolean.valueOf(stringToEval);

boolean b1 = Boolean.parseBoolean(stringToEval); // this also works 
...
if(b){
    printSomething();
} else printNothing();
...
```

Comment: Again, `args[0]` is *not* a value of `true` or `false` that can be trivially parsed to a `Boolean`. It's an expression that needs evaluating.

Answer (score -2):

So from what I understand the string args[0] is a boolean? Why not cast it to a boolean then?

```
boolean boolToEval = Boolean.parseBoolean(args[0]);
//OR
boolean boolToEval = Boolean.valueOf(args[0]);    

//THEN
(boolToEval ? printSomething() : printSomethingElse());
```

Comment: You did not see that! :P

Comment: He is not converting... He is using regular expressions in his arg[0]. Please read the question before you answer.

Comment: @AdelBoutros And where exactly does he say that?

Comment: @Voidpaw He isn't passing a regular expression, he's passing an expression, in this line in the question: `$ java MyProgram x==y`. He wants to evaluate `x==y` and apply the expression to some variables `x` and `y`.

Comment: @ChrisMantle so who mentioned regex? That was Adel Boutros for as far as I can see?

Comment: @Voidpaw Yeah, probably just a simple mix-up in terminology.